# MVC 4 razor model with multiple angle brackets issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am experiencing some issues with asp.net mvc 4
I want to use

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>
```

as a model for my view.

For some reason i am getting an error `An opening "<" is missing the corresponding closing ">"`.

I can create separate model which would contains my dictionary as a work around.

But i am just wondering is it a bug?

I was playing with that but cant make it work anyway then just for test i copy my model declaration to the View in MVC 3 project and it is looking good there, so it is something wrong with MVC 4.

Comment: Just for kicks, try this: `@using System.Collections.Generic` and `@model Dictionary < string, List < string > >` and see what happens.

Comment: @xixonia i was playing around with that, no way.

Comment: You could always create a custom view model :/

Comment: It's hard to tell if this is a Razor parsing issue or a compiler issue because when I hover over the brackets, it's highlighting correctly.

Comment: It looks like a razor parser issue because I am having the same issue on coloring feature on VS.

Comment: FYI, I just reported this issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/716165/asp-net-mvc-4-dev-preview-razor-view-engine-multiple-angle-brackets-incompatibility

Comment: This is a known bug and has been fixed! Thanks for reporting it @tugberk :). If you think you've got a bug, definitely file it on Connect, they go right into our Bug DB.

Comment: @AndrewNurse thanks, I'll do that :)

Comment: I just encountered the same issue. I'm using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.3 with Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3. How did you fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and the solution was to re-install the latest [ASP.Net MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4) framework. I also re-installed [ASP.NET Web Pages with Razor Syntax](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15979).